Array.prototype.sort() does not preserve element types for tuples
Simple sample works as expected:
type Data = {
    a: number
    b: number
}

const data: Data[] = [
    {a :1, b: 1},
    {a: 2, b: 2}
].sort((el1, el2) => el1.a - el2.a)

sorting works, type is preserved.
But it does not work for array of tuples:
type Data = [number, number]

const data: Data[] = [ // error: Type number[][] is not assignable to type Data[]
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])

And with heterogeneous items it's even worse:
type Data = [number, boolean]

const data: Data[] = [ // error: Type '(number | boolean)[][]' is not assignable to type 'Data[]'
    [1, true],
    [3, false]
].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
//      ^? (parameter) a: (number | boolean)[]

Are my types conceptually wrong? Or is it a known limitation and, if yes, is there a workaround?
I know .sort() mutates an array. But since top-level is not a tuple, I'd expect TypeScript preserve result type and properly infer element's type inside of .sort().

TS can't reach back through sort() to infer that [1, 2] should be interpreted as Data and not number[]. If you want to tell it that, you can do something like this. Your last example I don't get, why would [number, boolean] have anything to do with Data? Please [edit] the last example to make sense (or clarify why you've got it the way it is), and let me know if satisfies Data[] addresses your question or if I'm missing something so I can either write an answer/find a duplicate or get more clarification.

Or, without satisfies, since you're already explicitly typing your data anyway, in two instructions: const data: Data[] = [[1, 2],[3,4]]; data.sort(…).

@jcalz sorry for last sample. fixed.

satisfies helps. as helps(but I understand that satisfies is better). splitting onto assignment and .sort() call helps.
now I understand that my mistake was calling .sort() on literal data which was not typed yet, so results represent the best try of TS to infer typing on the original data.

if question seems too obvious, let's close it, I guess?

I don’t think it’s obvious… I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance

In order for
const data: Data[] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]].sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

to work as-is, TypeScript would need to infer the type of the array literal by contextually propagating the expected return type of Data[] back through the call to sort(), in order to see that [[1, 2], [3, 4]] must also be Data[].  But contextual type inference doesn't consistently reach back through method calls that way.  It's a limitation of the language. Similar issues can be seen at microsoft/Typescript#29771 and microsoft/TypeScript#47440.
What happens instead is that [[1, 2], [3, 4]] ends up getting the default non-contextual inferred type of number[][], and then sort() returns number[][], and the assignment fails.

This can be worked around in any number of ways all of which involve the developer specifying more explicit types rather than relying on inference.
My suggestion here would be to give [[1, 2], [3, 4]] a contextual type of Data[] by using the satisfies operator:
const data: Data[] = ([
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
] satisfies Data[]).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]) // okay

You could also just write
const data = ([
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
] satisfies Data[]).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]) // okay

and the inferred type of data will be equivalent to Data[]. Both of these versions have the advantage of not changing your runtime code (plus or minus some parentheses) and being relatively type safe (as opposed to using the as type assertion operator).
Playground link to code
